# How to increase the size of and size of text inside a submit-input?

Tags: html, css

Someone told me that I should be using `<button>`s, but I was taught that  should only be used when you have a multi-line submit-button; otherwise, use `<input type="submit" />`.

So I have these submit-input for some of the letters in the alphabet, but they are so small and the text inside them is so small.

I tried to increase their height and width, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Padding increase doesn't help and irrational font-sizes (46000%) only make it >5px bigger.

How can I increase the size of these inputs and the text inside them?

```
<input class="letter" id="a" type="submit" value="a" />
<input class="letter" id="c" type="submit" value="c" />
<input class="letter" id="e" type="submit" value="e" />
<input class="letter" id="f" type="submit" value="f" />
<input class="letter" id="g" type="submit" value="g" />
<input class="letter" id="h" type="submit" value="h" />
<input class="letter" id="i" type="submit" value="i" />
<input class="letter" id="k" type="submit" value="k" />
<input class="letter" id="l" type="submit" value="l" />
<input class="letter" id="m" type="submit" value="m" />
<input class="letter" id="n" type="submit" value="n" />
<input class="letter" id="o" type="submit" value="o" />
<input class="letter" id="p" type="submit" value="p" />
<input class="letter" id="r" type="submit" value="r" />
<input class="letter" id="s" type="submit" value="s" />
<input class="letter" id="t" type="submit" value="t" />
```

I currently have no CSS applied to them. A HTML5 reset / normalize.css might be affecting them.

Comment: I think we'll need more information: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/YVgv9/

Comment: are you using Chrome Developer Tools?  It allows you to see the CSS styles applied to each element; perhaps that can help

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you're getting/seeing... :)

Comment: @ExplosionPills That is the size they are, but when I try to increase them in the JSFiddle, it doesn't increase.

Comment: @GW I love Dev tools! Yes, there are no other styles being applied to it.

Comment: @IrfanMir what do you mean when you try to increase them in JSFiddle?  Can you go through your steps to do that?

Comment: @LenielMacaferi They are exactly the same size as in the fiddle. And they don't increase in the fiddle either. Fiddle in first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try these, either way will do:

**1st way:**

With your HTML:

```
<input id="a" type="submit" value="a" />
```

With your CSS:

```
input[type=submit]
{
    /* your styles here, You can just increase its font size below*/
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: ariel; 
    background-color: #ffedca;
}
```

**2nd Option**

With your HTML:

```
<input class="letter" id="a" type="submit" value="a" />
```

With your CSS:

```
.letter
{
    /* your styles here, You can just increase its font size below*/
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: ariel; 
    background-color: #ffedca;
}
```

Comment: Increasing font-size doesn't work. No matter what selector I apply it to.

Comment: where did you place your Css/style script?

Comment: Scripts right before the body closing tag, css in the head. but neither is styling the inputs.

Comment: no, but I can link to it. Click the white 'hint' text to see the inputs: http://the-irf.com/dev/

Comment: I guess, there's no letter named style from your page source that designates its font-size. can you check on it?

Comment: @IrfanMir, any relevant additional information that helps in seeing what the problem is should be added to the *question*, not just disclosed in a comment.

Comment: @lexeRoy Yes, I never give a font-size to the letter class as I tried that and not much happened.

Answer (score 1):

At http://the-irf.com/dev/ (the address of the page, disclosed in a comment), there is an apparent attempt at increasing font size with the following CSS code:

```
    .hint input{
        color:#333333;
        color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:161.8%;
        font-size:1.618rem;
    }
```

It has no effect, however, since the page does not have any `class` attribute that assigns the class `hint` to any element.

There is the attribute `id="hint"`, and changing the selector `.hint` to `#hint` makes the buttons bigger.

Comment: Seriously. I am so sorry. I must have planned to use hint as a class, but then turned it into an id when I only used it once.

Comment: I changed it to #hint input in my local copy and it is still not increasing in size. It is like it has a max-font-size. I tried it in developer tools and it doesn't get any bigger than 97%.

Comment: I tested this in Firefox with Web Developer Tools, editing the CSS on the fly, and the change took effect. Try editing your online page to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try ::
    .letter{width:150px}

Answer (score 0):

```
You can write it inside the input button.    
style="font-weight: bold;font-size:20pt;"
```

By: Aneel Goplani. B.SC. CIS. 2002. USA.

Comment: Typically we want to avoid inline css as much as possible

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust the size of inputs by setting the width and height in your css, or let it resize automatically by only setting the font size. To keep sizes consistent across the buttons you can set min-heights and widths.

In your css:

```
input{
    font-size:36pt;
    min-width:65px;min-height:65px;
}
```

An example is here - http://jsfiddle.net/FfkaV/3

Comment: I need them larger than that. When I tried to increase them any more, it would't go any bigger. Something like a 65x65 square.

Comment: you can set minimum heights and widths for your input, and then adjust the font size to suit it. I have updated my answer to reflect this,

Comment: see, but when I try to make it obnoxiously big, right now it is too big, it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/FfkaV/4/

Comment: It doesn't work on Chrome on OS X. The fonts are all the default (small) fonts. Chrome on OS X ignores font-size within input elements.